# NPE during invocation of maven-war-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

During a multimodule build, an error is surfaced in eclipse as follows:

`Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:exploded failed. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:exploded:default:process-resources)`

The stack trace for this error is

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:exploded failed.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:332)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1379)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:54)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:515)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:405)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction$1.run(GlobalBuildAction.java:180)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo$DefaultWarPackagingContext$1.visitFile(AbstractWarMojo.java:661)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo$DefaultWarPackagingContext$1.visitFile(AbstractWarMojo.java:656)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2804)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2876)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo$DefaultWarPackagingContext.<init>(AbstractWarMojo.java:655)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:520)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:453)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.WarExplodedMojo.execute(WarExplodedMojo.java:43)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
... 31 more
pom.xml /my-legacy-app line 1753 Maven Build Problem
```

I've debugged into AbstractWarMojo.visitFile, and there session.getStartTime() is null, so the call to getTime() throws an NPE.
Attempting to track down why the start time is null led me to MavenImpl, at which point I've gotten a bit stuck trying to
further track down the issue. I think it was pointing to something in MavenExecutionContext, but I'm not entirely sure.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Eclipse Version: 20200910-1200

m2e Version: 1.16.1.20200710-1008

Answer (score 0):

This was due to code introduced in version 3.3.1 of the maven-war-plugin, using 3.3.0 solves the problem.